# Searching for records of wmf files with a hex editor

Tags: encoding, hex, endianness, wmf

According to the wmf specification, data are stored in little indian format, whereas The byte numbering used for bitfields is big-endian. The RecordType Enumeration for META_SETMAPMODE = 0x0103.

However, when i open the wmf file with a hex editor and  search for  the value 01 03, no results are returned.
The WMF includes this record 100%. In the specification it is also stated that "The lower byte MUST match the lower byte of the RecordType Enumeration".

What  am I doing wrong?

Any ideas or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was pretty straightforward. Because the byte numbering used for bitfields is big-endian the order is reversed. Example for the RecordType Enumeration for META_SETMAPMODE, which is 0x0103, it is stored as 03 01.